# Why can’t visual studio open tinyfiledialogs.h?

Tags: include, header-files, include-path

[image: the additional include directories settings things]

It says there is no such file or directory

i put header file in header files and source file in source files and put the directory for the files in “additional include directories” and i thought the error would begone after that

Comment: Some screenshots of the config dialog and detail of your folder layout and project file location would help.  Just telling us effectively: "_I did everything right, what's wrong_", is not helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.